# Movie about a Male Siren?

Tags: identify-this-movie

My girlfriend saw a movie and asked me to find it:

> Is about a boy in High School that is in the swimming team as he is a very good athlete.
>   But one day his skin starts to become flakes with the touch of water. 
>   Later in the movie he discovers his mother was a siren or something like that.

The movie is probably american, and around year 2000? not sure.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: but its already identified :O

Comment: Yet quality isn't about answerability. We're not a one-shot identification service here but strive to provide an archive of useful, engaging and good questions about movies and TV-shows and there is definitely room for improvement here.

Comment: well, now answering the other thing, i didnt write more cause i dont know any extra information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a Disney TV movie **The Thirteenth Year (1999)**

> When Cody Griffin turns 13, things are going good. He is a star
>   swimmer, he is getting interest from a girl named Sam, and he has a
>   supportive family. Then he discovers that he may be turning into a
>   fish. He also discovers who his true friends are. [(IMDB)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0200208/)

[image]

[Promo on TV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cb74tVTW_2I)

Comment: thanks! i'll ask her if its the one, but seems right!

Comment: yes it is :D nice